# How do i obtain private organization information using application id + secret?

Tags: github, github-api

I have created an application and have granted it access to my organization using the *user:email* and *read:org* scopes.

Now i would like to list all teams in that organization. Using a curl request i get a *401 Requires Authentication* error.

This is my request:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/orgs/MyOrg/teams?client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET
```

If i look for members instead, i only get the public members of the organization:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/orgs/MyOrg/members?client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET
```

Do i need to obtain an access token for the application? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a personal access token of a user that has enough privileges to see all the teams in the organisation, and to make the request using that token. An application itself cannot ask for those things (though this will change with GitHub's upcoming [Integrations](https://developer.github.com/early-access/integrations/)).